# factory reset ubuntu 18.4 without usb drive

Tags: system-installation

is there any way that i can factory reset Ubuntu 18.4 in my laptop without using external media .
is there any way to reinstall operating system which will remove existing package .
thank you

Comment: If you have installed Ubuntu the standard way, no. But if you want this option, you can add a ['grub-n-iso'](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot) system: Add a menuentry in your grub menu that points to the Ubuntu iso file, and boot that way. This way you can run the installer and reinstall Ubuntu to the same partition(s), and get the original system again. - But I would recommend that you keep a USB pendrive or DVD disk or memory card that is bootable with Ubuntu, and use that to run the installer and reinstall Ubuntu to the same partition(s), and get the original system again.

Comment: thanks  i have installed Ubuntu in standard way.. so i will install normally..

Comment: You are welcome and good luck :-)